# Why do I get "ambiguous type variable" error here?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

```
import Data.Monoid

times :: Monoid a => Int -> a -> a
times i = mconcat . replicate i

main =
  print $ times 5 5
```

This code gives the following error:

```
Ambiguous type variable `a0' in the constraints:
  (Monoid a0) arising from a use of `times'
              at :7:11-15
  (Show a0) arising from a use of `print'
            at :7:3-7
  (Num a0) arising from the literal `5'
           at :7:19
Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
In the second argument of `($)', namely `times 5 5'
In the expression: print $ times 5 5
In an equation for `main': main = print $ times 5 5
```

Why does it give this error? How is `Num` even involved here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that there are *two* monoids defined for numbers. One with addition, and one with multiplication. These are implemented as instances for the newtypes `Sum` and `Product`, and you have to specify which one you want, as there are no monoid instances for plain numeric types.

```
*Main> times 5 (Sum 5)
Sum {getSum = 25}
*Main> times 5 (Product 5)
Product {getProduct = 3125}
```

`Num` is mentioned because `5` is a polymorphic value:

```
*Main> :t 5
5 :: Num a => a
```

This would normally cause ambiguous type errors all over the place, if not for *type defaulting*, which causes the compiler to go through a set of default types (normally `Integer` and `Double`), and choose the first one that fits. Since neither `Integer` nor `Double` has a `Monoid` instance, type defaulting fails, and you get the ambiguous type error.

It's also possible that you meant to use the list monoid, as it's not clear from the question what result you were expecting.

```
*Main> times 5 [5]
[5,5,5,5,5]
```

Comment: Thanks, hammar. I made a few changes to the code, and now I get a new error: http://paste.pocoo.org/show/486225/. (This actually should be a separate question, and I would make a new thread if you ask for it.)

Comment: @missingfaktor: That instance requires the `UndecidableInstances` extension.

Comment: I was indeed expecting a `Monoid` instance for `Int` but didn't know there isn't one.

Comment: (In response to your comment) Why?

Comment: @missingfaktor: Basically it's because instance selection is no longer guaranteed to terminate, if the type does not get "smaller" at each step. For example, there could be an `instance Num a => Monoid a`, or a loop that goes via more instances. This would cause the compiler to go in an infinite loop. The `UndecidableInstances` extension removes this requirement, and it's now up to you, the programmer, not to define instances that would cause infinite loops at compile time.

Comment: @missingfaktor Also, that instance doesn't do what you're thinking it does. If you add that instance, you won't be able to use *any* of the other instances of `Monoid` that have already been defined -- since that one *always* matches.

Comment: @DanielWagner, @hammar: Okay, I guess it'd be better to use `Sum` and `Product` wrappers then. Thanks for the help!